# Convert pandas json for highstock data format in a angularjs controller

Tags: python, angularjs, pandas, highcharts

I'm breaking my head on how to convert from a json to the highstock array format for a Series chart.

In my code I do the follow:

```
df2.reset_index().to_json(orient='records')
```

which results in this (for example):

```
[{"date":1456185600000,"adj_close":94.69},
{"date":1456099200000,"adj_close":96.88},
{"date":1455840000000,"adj_close":96.04},
{"date":1455753600000,"adj_close":96.26}]
```

then I get that json at my angularjs controller as an array of Objects, and I don't know how to transform that to the highstock format, to this for example:

```
 [
 [1456185600000, 94.69],
 [1456099200000, 96.88],
 [1455840000000, 96.04],
 [1455753600000, 96.26],
 ]
```

what should I do to make this conversion?

Comment: Hi tks for the help ;) and yes, I've updated the example for one that I have here, in fact the right separator is ',' , tks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d = [{"date":1456185600000,"adj_close":94.69},
{"date":1456099200000,"adj_close":96.88},
{"date":1455840000000,"adj_close":96.04},
{"date":1455753600000,"adj_close":96.26}]
```

Then a list comprehension like this

```
[[di['date'], di['adj_close']] for di in d]
```

gives you the desired output:

```
[[1456185600000, 94.69],
 [1456099200000, 96.88],
 [1455840000000, 96.04],
 [1455753600000, 96.26]]
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use the Array.map() method to reformat the objects:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

```js
var objectArray = [
  {"date":1456185600000,"adj_close":94.69},
  {"date":1456099200000,"adj_close":96.88},
  {"date":1455840000000,"adj_close":96.04},
  {"date":1455753600000,"adj_close":96.26}]

var highStockSeries = objectArray.map(function(object){
  return [object.date, object.adj_close]
})

console.log(highStockSeries)
```

```html
 <div id="result">look in the JS console for your array</div>
```